# How to get height and width of Button

Tags: android

I have created an array of buttons. Now I want to find the height and width of the button, and for that, I have used `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`. But the thing is that it always returns 0. Why is this happening? I have send my code, please check if anything is wrong.

```
LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
LinearLayout rowLayout = null;
LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DBFacade dbFacade = new DBFacade();
    dbFacade.pick();
}

//Create Button
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
rowLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
rowLayout.setWeightSum(7);
layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,param);

for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
{
m_pBtnDay[i][j]=new Button(this);

rowLayout.addView(m_pBtnDay[i][j],param);

m_pBtnDay[i][j].setOnLongClickListener(this);

m_pBtnDay[i][j].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
m_pBtnDay[i][j].setTextSize(12);
}
}
x=m_pBtnDay[i][j].getWidth();
y=m_pBtnDay[i][j].getHeight();
Log.d("width",Integer.toString(x));
Log.d("Height",Integer.toString(y));
return true;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably you are calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` too early: I think the UI has not been sized and laid out on the screen yet...
You can try to put that code inside this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    // Call here getWidth() and getHeight()
 }
```

Comment: so when i should call these function.I have gone through many examples but cant get the answer..can u please help me to solve these out

Comment: @Anshuman: create dinamically layout and let it show before checking width and height. In my edited code I provided an example, but I'm sure it's not the only one...

Comment: @Anshuman: you didn't tell us in which function/event you are calling your code...

Comment: Yeh when i write the code for getWidth and getHeight on  onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) and gives me the result.And is it true that for different Resolution it gives different width and height

Comment: Thanks; this fixed the problem. (Calling methods too early) Try to set getWidth after you call `show` on the `Scene`

Comment: Aha, that is the answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Another way

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = button.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        width = button.getWidth();
        height = button.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

put this in your loop

```
x =  m_pBtnDay[i][j].getWidth();
y =  m_pBtnDay[i][j].getHeight();
Log.d("width", Integer.toString(x));
Log.d("Height", Integer.toString(y));
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

You try to use the count-variable "i" and "j" to use outside from both for-loops. That should raise an exception because the are only availabil in each for-block.

Try to make the output in the second for-loop...

```
for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
    ...
    for(int j=0; j<7; j++)
    {
        ....   
        x =  m_pBtnDay[i][j].getWidth();
        y =  m_pBtnDay[i][j].getHeight();
        Log.d("width", Integer.toString(x));
        Log.d("Height", Integer.toString(y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the following View method, called during the layout phase.

```
protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
```

This seems more appropriate, as it expressly accounts for the zero width and height you're observing:

> This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed.
>   If you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the
>   old values of 0.
>
> Parameters w  Current width of this view. h   Current height of this
>   view. oldw    Old width of this view. oldh    Old height of this view.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score -1):

Try this can also work:

```
btn.getDrawingCache().getHeight() and btn.getDrawingCache().getWidth()
```