# Paste is not working on Oncreate? Android Clipboard

Tags: android

There is a strange behavior of Android copy paste. If I use handler paste is working but on oncreate and onstart it is not.

**Activity**

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_files);
    initView();

    Log.e("TAG", "onCreate1: " + C.paste(Verify_files.this) );
    new Handler(getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.e("TAG", "onCreate2: " + C.paste(Verify_files.this) );
        }
    },400);
```

**Logs** are here. primary clip is false then it becomes true

```
E/##CC: paste: false
E/TAG: onCreate1: 
E/##CC: paste: true
E/TAG: onCreate2: THIS IS TEXT TO PASTE
```

**Copy() Paste()**

```
    public static void copy(Context context , String text){
    Log.e(TAG, "copy: "+text );

    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService( CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "THIS IS TEXT TO PASTE");
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

    Toast.makeText(context,text+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public static String paste(Context context  ){
    ClipboardManager clipboard= (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    Log.e(TAG, "paste: "  +clipboard.hasPrimaryClip() );

    if(clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
        ClipData clip = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
         if (clip != null) {
            ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
            return item.getText() + "";
        }
    }
    return  "";

}
```

Comment: Could you try onResume? [getPrimaryClip](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager#getPrimaryClip()) returns false when the window is not in focus, and I think the activity is still in background untill it finishes loading.

Comment: E/TAG: onStart: false
E/TAG: onResume: false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approached you can do here.

First, by using `ViewTreeObserver`. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8741821/9346054

```
private void listenToViewTreeObserver(){
    final ViewTreeObserver vto = findViewById(R.id.text_view_something).getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // do something now when the object is loaded
            // e.g. find the real size of it etc
            Log.e("TAG", "onCreate: onGlobalLayout: " + paste(MainActivity.this) );
            findViewById(R.id.text_view_something).getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Second, by using `MessageQueue`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41276825/9346054

```
private void listenToMessageQueue(){
   final MessageQueue.IdleHandler handler = () -> {
        Log.e("TAG", "onCreate: IdleHandler: " + paste(MainActivity.this) );
        return false;
    };
    Looper.myQueue().addIdleHandler(handler);
}
```

At your `onCreate`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    copy(MainActivity.this,"Here");

    listenToMessageQueue();
    listenToViewTreeObserver();
}
```

Comment: Your answer has improved my knowledge.  Do you know why clipboard doesn't have primary clip on oncreate onstart onresume..? but later it can be accessed? is it because of activity context?

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli it can be only access when the view is fully complete.