# Is there a way of knowing how a view is null, even though it was declared and called?

Tags: android, kotlin

*EDIT* Ok guys, I was literally trying to call the FAB which is inside the fragment_home, in another fragment, my mistake, I should've called inside the Homefragment, I just changed it and it works now, thank you to everyone that help.

*TO ANYONE THAT GETS THE SAME ERROR*
-Check if you declared the ID of the view well
-Check if you are inside that activity class (activity_main.xml -> MainActivity.kt)
-Call the view correctly.
IF that doesn't solve it, you will find great answers down below, good luck.

I have this fab, declared here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BaseFragment"
    android:background="@color/darkBlack">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_notes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="@string/notes"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        app:queryHint="Search..."
        app:defaultQueryHint="Search..."
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.search"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_notes"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_view" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkBlack"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_check_24"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_insert_link_24"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:id="@+id/fabBtnCreateNote"
        android:tint="@color/yellow"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:contentDescription="Fab" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am calling it here:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext

abstract class BaseFragment() : Fragment(), CoroutineScope {

    private lateinit var job: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job +Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        var fab = view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fabBtnCreateNote)

        //Line throwing the error ->
        fab.setOnClickListener{
            replaceFragment(CreateNoteFragment.newInstance(), true)
        }
    }


    open fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, istransition:Boolean) {
        val fragmentTransition = activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        if(istransition) {
            fragmentTransition.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left)
        }

        fragmentTransition.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName).commit()
    }
}
```

I have declared it and am know calling it (I have android-kotlin-extensions) but it is throwing me a null object error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

It is pointing to the fabBtnCreateNote.setOnClickListener{} line.

I am not understanding what this means, could anyone help me out?

Comment: @a_local_nobody could you elaborate please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have seen that answer, but I haven't understood much and I can't get my head around what I am doing wrong, can I get some help?

Comment: what are you doing in onCreateView ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have this fab, I am calling that fab which is replacing the home fragment with another one (similar to when you are creating a new tweet), that fab is supposed to open that new fragment but it just throws that error

Comment: that doesn't answer my question - `what are you doing in onCreateView?`

Comment: @a_local_nobody From my little understanding here, I think that I am calling the fab and  defining what happens when I click it

Comment: "Is there a way of knowing how a view is null, even though it was declared and called?" This is not enough. You also need to **initialize** the variable. For a view, this is usually done with `view.findViewById()`.

Comment: no, you have to look at what i'm asking carefully :) i'm not asking what are you doing inside `onViewCreated`, i'm asking what are you doing `onCreateView` - they are different

Comment: @TomasMota You are not "calling" the fab. You can only call methods, but here `fabBtnCreateNote` is a variable. You are calling `setOnClickListener()` with that variable to define what happens when the user clicks on it. But you did not intialize `fabBtnCreateNote`.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have tried that, I have edited it to show what I have done there

Comment: i wrote an answer, maybe it helps you out

Comment: Check your imported file. Sometimes it happens when you import wrong xml file in your fragment. And that view which you want to access ( in ur case fabBtnCreateNote) happened to be present in that xml file too. Then this kind of scenario can be created .

Comment: @rafi I just added more information, I believe that could have caused it...

Comment: Your `BaseFragment` is `abstract`. What are the concrete classes doing, returning another layout from `onCreateView()` without the FAB in the layout?

Comment: Why not trying to use the recomanded way which is ViewBindig

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 2):

Try using the "findViewById" function like in this answer:

[Android setOnClickListener method - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803727/android-setonclicklistener-method-how-does-it-work)

I haven't done this stuff in a while, but I think the @id attribute only creates a string id which you have to access through R. and use to return the actual view.

EDIT: responding to your edit:
You have to do:

```
var fabBtnCreateNote = view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fabBtnCreateNote)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have just edited the post to show just that, I did it but still get the same error.

Comment: I tried it, replacing the fabs id with "view", but I still get that error

Comment: @TomasMota If you are still getting an NPE, please tell us which line causes it. Right now we are only guessing where the problem is. If you tell us exactly which line causes the problem, we can better help you. Also be sure to read the link under your question that explains what a NPE is so you can start learning how to figure out these kinds of problems on your own in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much man, I just added a comment on the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: @TomasMota I'm assuming its an error with the same line. At this point, I suspect this subview is not in the "View" object passed to ```onViewCreated``` and I would try logging all the subviews to double check like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749824/android-get-all-subviews-of-a-view

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I am going to read it and try it, I'll give you a feedback.

Comment: Thank you, I was declaring this function inside the wrong file... Thank you for your time. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

```
var fab = fabBtnCreateNote.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fabBtnCreateNote)
```

This is getting closer. However, you probably still get a NPE because `fabBtnCreateNote` is `null`. Instead, try this:

```
var fabBtnCreateNote = view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fabBtnCreateNote)
```

Note that you need to call `findViewById()` with `view` because this is the parent which contains the FAB.

Now that `fabBtnCreateNote` has a valid reference to the FAB view object, you can call methods on it, such as `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have made an edit. I have tried that, but it still throws the error :(

Comment: @TomasMota Which line causes the NPE now?

Comment: It is still the same line, I have added the whole class so you may get a better view on what I am trying to do. Thank you

Comment: @TomasMota This sounds like the id you pass into `findViewById()` doesn't exist in the current `view`. Double check that the id `fabBtnCreateNote` exists in the XML file for your fragment. Double check the spelling. Double check that you are looking at the correct XML file (is the FAB in the XML file for the parent activity instead?).

Comment: I think we just made a small step. I have the fab inside the fragment_home, but I am calling it inside the BaseFragment, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Thank you, I was declaring this function inside the wrong file... Thank you for your time. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically want to use synthetics, you can consider this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false)
}
```

then use

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        yourButton.whatever
    }
```

---

because `onCreateView` occurs before `onViewCreated`, so inside onViewCreated you can access your button

Comment: Thank you for your time. I do not have the onCreateView function, should I have it?

Comment: override it yes

Comment: Ok I have added that, but still get the same error, I will add it all in the answer, thank you.

Comment: 2 things then, firstly, are you sure the fab is inside `fragment_home` ? secondly, don't make use of findViewById for my solution, just use what i have here, although i doubt that will make a difference

Comment: Yes! I am 100% sure it is inside the fragment_home. Could the problem be that I have defined the view inside the fragment_home and I am calling it inside the BaseFragment????

Comment: Thank you, I was declaring this function inside the wrong file... Thank you for your time. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER**

Ok guys, I was literally trying to call the FAB which is inside the fragment_home, in another fragment, my mistake, I should've called inside the Homefragment, I just changed it and it works now, thank you to everyone that help.

TO ANYONE THAT GETS THE SAME ERROR

- Check if you declared the ID of the view well
- Check if you are inside that activity class (activity_main.xml -> MainActivity.kt)
- Call the view correctly.

**IF that doesn't solve it, you will find great answers down below, good luck.**

Consider reading:

Android setOnClickListener method - How does it work?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you solve the problem! To clarify terminology here, you are not calling the fab. Rather you are calling the method `setOnClickListener()` on a reference to an instance of `FloatingActionButton`. I think it is critical to have the correct terminology to describe what you are doing so that you can communicate clearly with others and think about it clearly.

Comment: Thank you very much, my man! I appreciate it. Have a nice one.